# Sentinel 5 Data - Problems in importing Basemap from mpl_toolkits.basemap in Python 3.7

Tags: python

I'm new in programming and I have some trouble with importing the basemap package to python 3.7. which i need to work with sentinel 5 data.
I downloaded the data for a couple of days and I want to zoom into a certain area in Europe. I want to plot the vertical column density of sulfuredioxid and create a timeline. is anyone experienced in working with sentinel 5 data in python?
I tried to work with the code below...

thank you!

I tried to install basemap but it didn't work. I tried to download it but it didn't work.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

Is it possible that this package doesn't exist anymore? Or isn't it working in python 3.7.?

[here is the code that I tried to use](http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/sentinel-5p-and-python/)

Comment: Hello, it seems like you forgot to post the code you are mentioning in the question. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56756240/edit) to include the code. It is also not clear what the question is - you are mentioning you have problems importing the basemap package - are you getting any errors?

Comment: Oh sorry...I edited my question

Comment: how did you install this package ? did you use pip or something else ?